# "'Form1' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types "

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, speech-to-text

I have this code which converts speech into text and prints it on listbox in Windows form  , but when i try to compile it in visual studio 2017  it wont compile because of error  " 'Form1' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types " .

Here is the logic :

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;
namespace WinFormSpeech
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre =
          new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.SpeechRecognized += sre_SpeechRecognized;
            Grammar g_HelloGoodbye = GetHelloGoodbyeGrammar();
            Grammar g_SetTextBox = GetTextBox1TextGrammar();
            sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g_HelloGoodbye);
            sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g_SetTextBox);
            // sre.RecognizeAsync() is in CheckBox event
        }
        static Grammar GetHelloGoodbyeGrammar()
        {
            Choices ch_HelloGoodbye = new Choices();
            ch_HelloGoodbye.Add("hello");
            ch_HelloGoodbye.Add("goodbye");
            GrammarBuilder gb_result =
              new GrammarBuilder(ch_HelloGoodbye);
            Grammar g_result = new Grammar(gb_result);
            return g_result;
        }
        static Grammar GetTextBox1TextGrammar()
        {
            Choices ch_Colors = new Choices();
            ch_Colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "white", "blue" });
            GrammarBuilder gb_result = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb_result.Append("set text box 1");
            gb_result.Append(ch_Colors);
            Grammar gi_result = new Grammar(gb_result);
            return gi_result;
        }
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender,
          EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            else if (checkBox1.Checked == false) // Turn off
                sre.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
        }
        void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender,
          SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = e.Result.Text;
            float conf = e.Result.Confidence;
            if (conf < 0.65) return;
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("I heard you say: "
              + txt);
            })); // WinForm specific
            if (txt.IndexOf("text") >= 0 && txt.IndexOf("box") >=
              0 && txt.IndexOf("1") >= 0)
            {
                string[] words = txt.Split(' ');
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                { textBox1.Text = words[4]; })); // WinForm specific
            }
        }
    } // Form
} // ns
```

And this is Designer code :

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WinFormSpeech
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(672, 42);
            this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 21);
            this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.checkBox1.Text = "Speech On";
            this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 42);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.ItemHeight = 16;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1, 97);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(771, 324);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    }
}
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `.ctor()` means the constructor, `public Form1() {...}`. But that's only defined once, that I can see. Did you try to clean the solution, restart VS, and rebuild?

Comment: ctor should be a abreviation of "Constructor". But short of you having a third part to this partial class, I do not see where you could have constructor duplication.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other file with `partial class Form1` with a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming your class to something other than Form1. If you have multiple classes with the same name in the same folder or namespace, sometimes visual studio can get confused.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this issue with a DevSkiller assessment. Builds fine in local VS (and dotnet CLI), but when I zip it and upload it, the DevSkiller compiler (same .NET Core version per output) gives me these errors that you'd expect if there were duplicate classes.

I remembered that I fixed a typo in the name of one of the folders ("Sevices" to "Services"), but the dotnet build CLI output in DevSkiller was showing these errors in "Sevices/..." as though I had not renamed the folder. The Namespace itself was spelled correctly from the get-go so.. If I didn't know better I'd say that DevSkiller is replacing any missing code with its own copy for some reason, maybe to address issues with missing non-code files preventing an otherwise-valid solution from building?

To test this theory, I tried uploading this DevSkiller solution with just the sln file, the "IMPORTANT" file and of course the devskiller.marker file. Still gives me the same build errors for files that shouldn't even exist...

It's possible my renaming the folder has borked this particular DevSkiller "session" irreparably. I don't think I'm getting the job, fellas!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a constructor defined in Form1 class in its class file i.e., Form1.cs. You can get to this file by further expanding the Form1.Designer.cs file.
So, from here on you can add your code inside your constructor i.e., Form1() into the Form1.cs file instead of creating another Form1() in Form1.Designer.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue just a minute ago when I was pushing it to Github and build using Github Action. The project can be built fine using both Visual Studio and `dotnet build`. But when I pushed to Github, it just tells me like your issue. So from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/808628/How-to-resolve-this-error-already-defines-a-member), I found that I just need to click on the function name, and then click rename then click Apply and the issue will go away!

Check [this (before)](https://github.com/raspiduino/OpenProductivity/actions/runs/912075698) and [this (after)](https://github.com/raspiduino/OpenProductivity/runs/2757966373?check_suite_focus=true) if you don't believe.